How do I monitor metrics specific to Server Sent Events (SSE) in Spring?
We are using a SpringBoot service that uses SseEmitter to implement Server Sent Events back to the client.
From the standpoint of observability, I am wondering if there are any metrics that are specific to SSE I should be aware of. This would be in addition to the standard HTTP metrics around status_code or latency, for example.
I am new to this, and uncertain of what types of things can occur in a production environment. Some examples of things I was considering:

the number of open connections
an event is sent to the client
an error occurs sending an event to the client for some reason
a connection is closed
a connection is opened

A look at Spring documentation and searching on the web has not yielded anything fruitful.
